# How to use "where" correctly

Tags: grammar

I thought about a particular example, and I was wondering if there's a problem when you use "where" in a situation where the thing in question are situated on the ship and not inside the ship. I don't think it's important, but I wasn't sure if it impacted the correctness of the sentence.

For example:

> A spaceship where the guns are made of a titanium alloy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is idiomatic, at least in speech, but using something other than a place before "where" in this type of phrase is a little awkward and maybe not formally correct. I would prefer either:

> A spaceship *whose* guns are made of a titanium alloy.

or (even better):

> A spaceship *with* guns [made] of titanium alloy.

("made" is optional in the last one - omitting it gives a more dramatic tone, like "man of steel" or "heart of gold.")